# USBKeyboard undefined when compiling for K22F

Tags: mbed

I'm compiling a very simple mBed OS 6 (bare metal) program that uses `USBKeyboard` for the FRDM-K22F, but I get this link error:

```
[Error] @0,0: L6218E: Undefined symbol USBKeyboard::key_code(unsigned char, unsigned char) (referred from BUILD/K22F/ARMC6/main.o).
[Error] @0,0: L6218E: Undefined symbol USBKeyboard::USBKeyboard(bool, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short) (referred from BUILD/K22F/ARMC6/main.o).
```

Those functions are defined in `USBKeyboard.cpp` but I'm not sure how to make mBed Studio actually link it.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on the Mbed forum too and got [a solution there](https://forums.mbed.com/t/usbkeyboard-undefined-when-compiling-for-k22f/12617/2):

> if you have in your mbed_app.json file only this content
>
> ```
> {
> "requires": ["bare-metal"]
> }
> ```
>
> then you probably need to change it to
>
> ```
> {
> "requires": ["bare-metal", "events", "drivers-usb"]
> }
> ```
>
> This seems to be incorrectly documented.